# Create a class function in Matlab

Tags: java, matlab

I have a class function in java code. I would like to make a class function in matlab that works similar with class function java. Could you help me to change it
This is my java code

```
 public class Return{
            byte m[][]; 
            int indcs[];            
            public Return(byte T[][], int ind[])        
            {                   
                this.m=T;
                this.indcs=ind;
            }

            public byte[][] getfirst(){
                return m;
            }           

            public int[] getsecond(){
                return indcs;
            }

}
```

Comment: Have a look [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/a-class-code-listing.html) and associated chapters, it's really not that different. On a side note I would recommend to avoid using `Return` as a class name. Although Matlab is case sensitive, it is rarely a good idea to use specific language keyword for variable or class name (unless overloading is intentional but it doesn't seem to be the case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following (note that it does not check variable type):

```
classdef Ret
    properties (Access = public)
        m = []
        indcs = []
    end

    methods (Access = public)
        function obj = Ret(T, ind)
            obj.m = T;
            obj.indcs = ind;
        end
        function x = getfirst(obj)
            x = obj.m;
        end
        function x = getsecond(obj)
            x = obj.indcs;
        end
    end
end
```

You don't have to use the `(Access = public)` - all properties and methods are public by default.